# Flutter Without Emulator

Tags: flutter

I cannot install the Android Emulator in my working environment, therefore I wondered whether it is possible to code/learn Flutter without any mobile device (or emulator). For example, is it possible to run/test the code by using the browser?

Comment: Not having an emulator or physical device seems to defeat the purpose of mobile development, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Genymotion has a cloud solution to run your app in web browser, I'm not affiliated with them https://www.genymotion.com/run-app-web-browser/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two non-mobile options, both of which are currently in development stages but could be used for learning Flutter:

- [flutter-desktop-embedding](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/), particularly the [example](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/example/README.md) which you can check out and `flutter run` with minimal setup, and then modify.
- The [Flutter for web](https://flutter.dev/web) technical preview.

Comment: Thank you, those two seem to be good alternative to non-mobile options.

Comment: Looks like Flutter for web is in beta now

Answer (score -3):

Flutter Desktop Launcher for Mac OS/Linux, support hot reload via VS Code

GitHub Link: https://github.com/putraxor/flutter_desktop_launcher

Comment: That project is a binary snapshot of an old version of the flutter-desktop-embedding project. It only works with one specific, old version of Flutter (which isn't documented, so you'd have to find it by trial and error), and doesn't support any of the new `flutter`-tool-based workflows that flutter-desktop-embedding now supports. Using the flutter-desktop-embedding project is a much better option.