# How can I run my Flutter projects on Windows instead of emulators?

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart

I have been wanting to run my projects directly on Windows for a long time, and after many inquiries from my friends, I found out that for this, a series of special settings are needed in Windows.
Help me please..

Comment: Do you mean transforming your [Flutter project into Windows executable](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/windows/building) OR do you mean running your Android app written in Flutter on a Windows PC with [Windows System for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/android/wsa/) (technically an emulator but provided by Microsoft)

Comment: This is a similar question on stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56216624/flutter-without-emulator